# Return numpy matrix from SWIG method using numpy.i

Tags: numpy, swig

I've found the following SWIG rule in [numpy.i](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/swig.interface-file.html) documentation.

```
    ( DATA_TYPE ARGOUT_ARRAY2[ANY][ANY] )
```

Frankly, this snippet gives no idea how to wrap a C++ function returning a 3*3 matrix. What does "ANY" mean? Suppose, I've got a function with a signature `void make_matrix(double** matrix)`. It allocates `3*3*sizeof(double)` bytes with malloc() and writes them to out parameter. Now to apply this rule? How to bind 3 to "ANY"? How to bind matrix to "ARGOUT_ARRAY2"? How to bind DATA_TYPE to double? Is there any kind of documentation covering these details?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs you cite (in the [Input Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/swig.interface-file.html#input-arrays) section):

> The first signature listed, `( DATA_TYPE IN_ARRAY[ANY] )` is for one-dimensional arrays with hard-coded dimensions. Likewise, `( DATA_TYPE IN_ARRAY2[ANY][ANY] )` is for two-dimensional arrays with hard-coded dimensions, and similarly for three-dimensional.

The all caps portions are place holders for the values you are actually using. Proper use is dependent on a thorough understanding of SWIG syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using the venerable [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) library to represent your matrices in C++, then there are some very useful SWIG [wrappers](https://github.com/Biomechanical-ToolKit/BTKCore/blob/master/Utilities/SWIG/eigen.i) available within the [Biomechanical Toolkit](https://github.com/Biomechanical-ToolKit/BTKCore) which allow `Eigen` matrices to be transparently converted into `numpy` arrays.

Your SWIG interface definition should contain something along the following lines:

```
%module(docstring="Simple SWIG+Eigen demo") myeigenswig
%include eigen.i
%include numpy.i

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include "mylibrary.hpp"
%}

%init %{
import_array();
%}

%eigen_typemaps(Eigen::VectorXd)
%eigen_typemaps(Eigen::MatrixXd)

Eigen::MatrixXd myFunction();
```

Another option, if you're not using Eigen, is to convert your 3x3 C++ array into a 9-element `std::vector<double>`, which SWIG will easily convert into a Python list, and which can then be turned into a numpy array by invoking `numpy.asarray(vectorFromCxx).reshape((3,3))`. This won't be especially efficient, involving quite a bit of copying between different data structures, but may be sufficient for your application unless you're passing many matrices between C++ & Python.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a single snippet returning fixed size array via output parameter using numpy.i. At the moment I've almost gave up and using my custom mapping which calls PyArray_SimpleNew with hardcoded params.